# Как установить Nextjs на хостинг?

Tags: nextjs

Создал проект на компе, доработал его. ошибок нет все запускается и работает на компе. Но теперь встал вопрос, что дальше? Долго искал ответы, находил разные статьи но ни чего не работает.  Купил VDS с Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker, через командную строку установил Nextjs с плясками и бубном. Но при запуске ни чего не происходит. Так же возникает вопрос как свои проект перенести на VDS ? Каким хостингом пользуйтесь?

Answer (score 0):

NextJS можно запускать в двух режимах: SSG и SSR.

В первом случае можно сформировать приложение в виде статических файлов (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) без использования сервера. В таком случае в качестве сервера можно настроить nginx  и использовать какой-нибудь сервис типа netlify.app для хостинга клиентских приложений.

Во втором случае запускается nodejs сервер (который вшит в NextJS), поэтому на VDS нужно сбилтить проект и запустить через `npx next start`  (подробнее здесь: https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server). В случае с VDS обычно еще ставится nginx, который проксирует запросы из внешнего мира в nodejs приложение (т.е. в нашем случае в nextjs). Подробнее можно почитать на https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04 (на сайте можно найти туториалы для любой версии ubuntu)

На рабочих проектах обычно все оборачивается в докер контейнер и деплоится через какое-нибудь внешнее или внутреннее облако.